# Get disabled dropdown value in pojo class without hidden input field

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Not able to get the disabled dropdown value in the Model class in Spring MVC.

I want a solution that doesn't require a hidden input field.

Comment: This question should be more specific. What errors are you getting? I have some ideas for instance you may need to ignore missing fields in the spring configuration but it is difficult to tell.

Comment: When my dropdown is disabled then the dropdown value is not being bonded to the model class of the controller.
Without disabling the dropdown, I am getting the value in the model class.
Thanks.